# The method add(Filters) in the type ArrayList<Filters> is not applicable for the arguments (Bson) in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

```
ArrayList<Filters> fieldList = new ArrayList();
fieldList.add(Filters.lte("ID", 5));
fieldList.add(Filters.lt("amount", 500));
Bson group = Aggregates.group("$NAME",id,name,amount); 
List<Object> results = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList( Aggregates.match((Bson) fieldList), Aggregates.group(group) )).into(new ArrayList<>());// error occurring here
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: in which line of code you showed us does the error occur?

Comment: You need arraylist of Bson. Something like `List<Bson> fieldList = new ArrayList();
`

Comment: i Have already tried it, getting the error: **java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.bson.conversions.Bson** @Veeram

Answer (score 1):

You can use `and` filter to add more filters.

```
Bson match = Aggregates.match(Filters.and(Filters.lte("ID", 5), Filters.lt("amount", 500)));
Bson group = Aggregates.group("$NAME", id, name, amount);
List<Document> results = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, group), Document.class).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: cant i add all the filter conditions to a list, because i never knows how many conditions come(they come from json)  @Veeram

Comment: You are still adding one at a time to the list. How does your json look like ? How do you know which operator to use against which field ?

Comment: i haven't thought of how i will pass parameter in json, Isn't it possible to add all filter conditions at a time to list,so that i can loop through the list and add to Aggregates.match() individually. any suggestion? @Veeram

Comment: You can if thats what you prefer. You mean something like this `List<Bson> fieldList = new ArrayList();
        fieldList.add(Filters.lte("ID", 5));
        fieldList.add(Filters.lt("amount", 500));
        Bson match = Aggregates.match(Filters.and(fieldList))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by @Veeram worked

solution:

```
  List<Bson> fieldList = new ArrayList(); 
    fieldList.add(Filters.lte("ID", 5)); 
    fieldList.add(Filters.lt("amount", 500)); 
    Bson match = Aggregates.match(Filters.and(fieldList));
```

by this i am able to add all filter conditions to a list.